# Did ListView reordering stop working on Windows 10 RT apps?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-10

I've got a simple ListView in my Windows 8.1 app running on Windows 10 (version 1511, build 10586.36):

```
<ListView 
        x:Name="ItemListView" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"        
        TabNavigation="Local"
        SelectionMode="None"
        AllowDrop="True" 
        IsSwipeEnabled="True"
        CanReorderItems="True"
        Padding="0"
        Margin="10"         
    />
```

My ViewModel just has a simple ObservableCollection of Items in it, and I'm using MVVMLight for the `RaisePropertyChanged()` implementation:

```
private ObservableCollection<Item> items;
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
        set {
            var oldVal = items;
            items = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Items", oldVal, items, true);
        }
    }
```

When I instantiate the ViewModel and set it to the Page's DataContext, I set up a List of Items, which have numbers in them (1 to 6) so I can see the difference between them and see whether or not the functionality is working properly.

The goal here is to reorder the Items by dragging the row from one place in the ListView and dropping it in another.  Reading the docs, this should work, and indeed it did as of a month ago.  I don't believe I've changed anything about the code since I last saw it working.  (I know, this is a claim that's hard to swallow.)

Now, what happens is that you can drag items and drop them in a different spot, but they pop back to their original position.  In other words, items can be dragged to different positions in the ListView, but they revert to their original position when dropped.

I suspect that a recent Windows 10 update broke this functionality (as it did with `CurrentApp.LicenseInformation`), but if anyone out there sees something here that I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate knowing what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue with Windows 10 build 10586 that is currently being investigated.

Follow https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/49a84f9f-69d7-4304-9cb7-ac44fd570252/w81-listview-canreorderitems-functionality-broken-in-windows-10-build-1511?forum=wpdevelop for details.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about that!  Hopefully, we'll see speedy resolution (to that and the IAP-breaking thing).